# Adding nodes to shipyard

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to create a docker swarm cluster in shipyard but i am unable to do so,
I created two virtualbox using docker-machine: mac1(suppose IP is 10.0.0.10) and mac2(suppose IP is 10.0.0.20)

I installed shipyard on mac1(10.0.0.10) using the command:

```
curl -sSL https://shipyard-project.com/deploy | bash -s
```

Then, I tried adding node mac2 to the cluster, for that:
1) I first switched to mac2 as the active machine:

```
eval $(docker-machine env mac2)
```

2) Now, i ran the following command as given on shipyard docs to add a node:

```
curl -sSL https://shipyard-project.com/deploy | ACTION=node DISCOVERY=etcd://10.0.1.10:4001 bash -s
```

output comes as Node added to the swarm, but i cannot see node being added in the nodes page in shipyard.

Can anyone tell me how to add nodes in shipyard

Comment: Did you open tcp ports 4001 and 2375 on 10.0.0.10?
Also, I have noticed you have provided DISCOVERY ip address as 10.0.1.10 instead of 10.0.0.10. This doesn't look right.

Btw, I was able to successfully add nodes in my environment to swarm cluster by following shipyard's automated deployment document.